# UI design tools

Tags: user-interface

I need to find some good tools for designing UI. I need only the design part, I don't need any code generation or anything like that... It would be nice to find some freeware ;)

tia

Comment: web?  windows forms? osx forms?  details please

Comment: a good UI design tool should be able to handle the majority of requirements

Comment: ideally would be to have evrything - web based apps and desktop based apps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean exactly by 'design'.

If you mean graphic design, as in you want to produce nice fancy graphics for your UI that you then slice up and integrate, then personally I always use [Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/) from Adobe (originally a Macromedia product). It's a vector based graphics tool so I find it much simpler to use than Photoshop or Illustrator. Not free however.

If you mean design as in laying out UI elements and experimenting with different ideas, e.g. for prototyping, then pen and paper is the best tool there is! Use sticky notes or a whiteboard to simulate changes in state, it's very easy to iterate and to prototype with users. There's even a [book](http://www.paperprototyping.com/) been written on it. If you need something digital but low-fi, then [Baclsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) is a good choice, or anything that lets you draw simple shapes (Paint!).

(the preview screwed up the hyperlinks, I'm hoping this will turn out better when posted...)

Comment: I'll stick with pen & paaper for several reasons:

1. it's fast, faster than any other app...
2. it's cheap ;)
3. you can prototype or sketch things in a bus/train/whatever so you don't have to pull out your laptop and start it up

for later stages of design I've found that Photoshop + Wacom Bamboo works like a charm, but I'll have to give Fireworks a try.. stil pen & paper (preferably your little sketchbook so you can review your older designs.)

Answer (score 8):

I've used [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) and have been real happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

The best free one I've found so far is [Pencil](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/), which can be installed as a stand-alone app or as a Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.lovelycharts.com the key is simplicity so that you don't get wrapped up in design details when creating your UI

Comment: I hope I wasn't down voted because I said ignore design and the OP asked for only the design part, because by UI design he doesn't mean making things look pretty, he means laying out a usuable & intuitive interface. Well that's how I interpret it anyway

Answer (score 2):

I find [Mockup Screens](http://www.mockupscreens.com/) really useful.

More posts on SO covering this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156937/do-you-know-an-alternative-to-balsamiq-mockups
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606/what-software-can-i-use-to-create-ui-mockups
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672/what-are-you-using-for-web-ui-layout-design

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Microsoft Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) . It is an awesome tool for UI designing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com), really handy and meet your requirements, they are offering free license now.

Answer (score 0):

High Visual Design Greatest - Adobe Photoshop  | Expression design | Gimp[Free]
Prototype - Expression Blend, PPT

here is my blog - http://artsmaths.blogspot.com/2009/03/tool-for-doing-ui-mockups.html